# Positioning buttons using CSS without tables

Tags: css, css-float

I'm pulling my hair out here trying to get CSS to position only a handful of html elements.

Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/7pTL8/

What I want is for "person@business.com [v]" to be at the top-right and then below it "Average Depth," "[x] Settings", and "Past 24 hours [v]" are all displayed together at the same level. I've tried floats and that had strange results. I don't want to resort to using a table here because everything I read about CSS suggests using tables for layout is a poor solution.

Comment: Try posting an image of your desired look, that would be a lot easier for people to understand when answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not as tuff as you think..
here is small solution.. its not very good but it can solve you problem for now..

[a link] http://jsfiddle.net/7pTL8/2/

```
<div id="user-selection">person@business.com [v]</div>
<div id="settings-container">
 <h1 id="graph-title">Average Depth</h1>
<span id="settings-button">[x] Settings</span>
<span id="timeframe-dropdown">Past 24 hours [v]</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
​#graph-title {
   position:absolute;
   left:1px;
   text-align: left;
}

#settings-container {
   text-align: right;
   }    

 #user-selection {
    text-align: right; 
  }
```

​

Answer (score 1):

`<span>` elements use `display:inline`, while `<h1>` elements use `block` by default. Manually override the #graph-title to use `display:inline` and it will line up with the rest of your elements:

```
#graph-title
{
    display:inline;       
}
​
```

Comment: H1 elements are `block`, by default, not `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably the use of `h1` element. By default `h1` has the style `display: block`. If you add the style `display: inline` it will be fine.

**EDIT:**
I think you ought to use `span` for it if you don't have any special reasons.